# unable to access model attributes in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, model, attributes

I created a model named Group. which have name,sesssionId attributes.
in my **index.html.erb** i added

```
<%=form_for(@group) do |f|%>
<%=f.text_field :name %>
<%=f.submit%>
<%end%>
```

in groups controller i stored attributes in Group model

```
def index
@group = Group.new
@groups = Group.all
end

def create
 #here i am getting "session" with some other code...
 params[:group][:sessionId] = session.session_id
 @group = Group.create(strong_param)
 #@group = Group.new(params[:group])
 if @group.save
   redirect_to("/room/"+@group.id.to_s)
 else
   render :controller => 'groups', :action => 'index'
 end
end

def room
end
private 
def strong_param
    params.require(:group).permit(:name,:sessionId)
end
```

in **room.html.erb**

```
<p>unique url for this room is <%=@group.id%></p>
```

when I tried to access group_id in room view it shows

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

I am unable to access those model attributes in above view. And i can able to access them in index view.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

The error is because you don't have `@group` in `room` method.

Try the below code

```
def room
  @group = Group.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In the controller action for the "/room/:id", to which you redirect the user after creating a group, the `@group` variable is not set, therefor you get the error.

Answer (score 1):

You should set `@group` in `room` action:

```
def room
  @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
end
```

I would also advice you to learn about routing in Rails, so you can clean your controller a little bit.